# Leanback Search fragment closing after gaining focus on results

Tags: android, leanback

In the leanback search fragment when we have committed a search with the keyboard and we have search results the fragment is closing when the search query is submitted with the back button. We can see that on action down of the back button the results are gaining focus and the keyboard is hiding(as expected) but on action up the screen is closing.

I believe this is a bug in the leanback framework since this is reproducing in the leanback showcase.

I have also posted an issue https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/issues/58

Is there a workaround to disable the closing of the screen?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem as you.
Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not yet, but I will be back on the task soon so I will find one. A possible dirty solution could be to disable the activity onBackPressed for some milliseconds after the focus gain of the results. But this won't fix the problem if you hold the back button.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the source of the bug.
In the SearchSupportFragment there is a searchBarListener that is giving focus on results in onKeyboardDismiss, but this is called before dispatchKeyEvent and when the back button is handled the results are already focused and the screen is closing.

I have found a hacky sololution of this until the Leanback team fix it. In onViewCreated I have set my own searchBarListener and I have delayed the focus change

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    //this is overriding the default searchResultProvider, because of a bug in it
    view.findViewById<SearchBar>(R.id.lb_search_bar).setSearchBarListener(object : SearchBar.SearchBarListener {
        override fun onSearchQueryChange(query: String?) {
            onQueryTextChange(query)
        }

        override fun onSearchQuerySubmit(query: String?) {
            onQueryTextSubmit(query)
        }

        override fun onKeyboardDismiss(query: String?) {
            searchHandler.postDelayed({ focusOnResults() }, 200)
        }
    })
}
```